# Django Appending Slashes to Static File URLs on OpenShift

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, python-3.x, openshift

I am attempting to deploy a Django 1.6 application on OpenShift using the Python 3.3 cartridge, but I have run into problems with static files. I have had partial success with the OpenShift IRC channel, tutorials/templates ([for](https://appsembler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/static_assets.html) [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)), and previous StackExchange questions ([for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595223/static-files-on-openshift-django/24656169#24656169) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24398718/django-and-openshift-static-files-cant-be-found)), but nothing has completely resolved the problem.

When I request the static content by URL (e.g. 'mydomain.com/static/stylesheet.css' or 'mydomain.com/static/icons/cog.svg') I can see them perfectly fine. When static files are used as SVG data for icons, they show up fine. Only when linking to a stylesheet have I run into problems. I use the following to include CSS in my template:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href={% static "stylesheet.css" %}/>
```

I have loaded the static files tag set with `{% load staticfiles %}`. Instead of seeing the stylesheet at `/static/stylesheet.css`, Django (I assume that it is Django, not Apache) looks for it at `/static/stylesheet.css/` (note the trailing slash). This causes the request to fail with a 404 status code. The same thing occurs when I use other file extensions (I have tried `.txt`, `.css`, and `.svg`) or link to a file contained in a subdirectory of `static`. It is only in this circumstance that an extra trailing slash is appended.

It is my understanding that Django appends a trailing slash to a URL in the event that the URL does not match any of the patterns defined in `urls.py`. Is it possible on OpenShift to configure Apache so that it directly handles all requests to URLs of the form `/static/*`? I have an `.htaccess` file in the `wsgi` directory with the commands

```
Rewrite Engine On
Rewrite Rule ^application/static/(.+)$ /static/$1 [L]
```

but this does not solve the problem. I have also tried using a rewrite rule for just the stylesheet as well as a few things with `Alias` but have had no luck there, either.

Should Django be getting the requests for these static files at all? I have confirmed that `DEBUG` is being set to `False` in my `settings.py` file, and make no mention of `django.views.static.serve` in my `urls.py` file. Here are the relevant parts of `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if 'OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR' in os.environ:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'),
                               'wsgi', 'static')
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
```

I do not set values for `STATICFILES_DIRS` or `STATICFILES_FINDERS` because at present I'm only dealing with static files found at `STATIC_ROOT`. The OpenShift project looks like

```
~/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/
    .htaccess
    application
    openshift/
        settings.py
        manage.py
        #And so on.
    static/
        stylesheet.css
        icons/
            cog.svg
            #More icons here.
```

This is my first time trying to deploy and I am stuck on this stumbling block. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `href={% static "stylesheet.css" %}`, try `href="{% static 'stylesheet.css' %}"`

Comment: I think you mean `href="{% static 'stylesheet.css' %}"`, as per [URL names](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names). Nevertheless, definitely +1 - I managed to completely miss the extra set of double-quotes previously.